# Using iron-ajax to grab string and insert onto page

Tags: ajax, rest, polymer, polymer-1.0

```
<template is="dom-bind">
    <iron-ajax
        auto
        url="http://localhost:9000/api/version"
        last-response="{{versionNumber}}"
        verbose
    ></iron-ajax>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{versionNumber}}">
        <small class="u-ml+">{{item.first}}</small>
    </template>
    <template>
        <small>[[versionNumber]]</small>
    </template>
</template>
```

I'm a little bit lost with Polymer - I have an `iron-ajax` element which is set up to talk an API endpoint, which is returning the current version of my application.

I want to be able to bind this version number directly on the page. Is there something I'm doing incorrectly in the above code?

I tried using a `dom-repeat` template and attempting to grab the first item, but I don't seem to be getting anything. Same with attempting to one-way bind inside of a `<small>` tag.

My understanding is that if I'm within a `dom-bind` template, I don't have to define a custom element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, data-binding works inside of a `dom-bind` template without the need for a custom element.

One problem in your code is the `template` tag around `<small>`

```
<template>
  <small>[[versionNumber]]</small>
</template>
```

The content of a template by itself won't be shown/rendered in the DOM. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/ for some detailed information about templates).

Using `<small>[[versionNumber]]</small>` inside of your `dom-bind` template with the extra template tag should work.

Another issue is, that `iron-ajax` by default handles responses as JSON, so will probably run into a parse error when it receives a string and `last-response` will get no value.

You would have to specify the [`handleAs`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#property-handleAs) property of iron-ajax accordingly.

`<iron-ajax handle-as="text" ...>`

And `dom-repeat` will only work for arrays.